# STM32F103C8 Debugging Using STM Studio (version 3.5.1)

Tags: stm32, debugging

I am trying to obtain real time variable reading in STM Studio But When My STM Board starts running program My STM Studio was unable to detect STLInk V2 and My program Runs only in Flash Mode.
I am using ST Link Utility for programming My STM32 Board. In my program I toggle LED to know that program is running. And I also declared variables for real time debugging.
   The Board does not start to run program when programming is done using ST Link Utility. Instead when I set device to flash mode code runs but device is not detected by STM Studio and ST Link Utility.

Comment: Perhaps your program is reconfiguring the SWD pins for a different purpose?

Comment: It's is possible the device is not detected because the serial wire pins are not enabled,it happened with me when i used a generic stlink v2 clone to program stm32f103c8 using stm32cubeMx and truestudio,the solution was to select the peripheral function of the dedicated pin in stm32cube itself. you uploaded the code using SWD or USART?